# Converting SKScene to a Video

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to develop a real time video editor with SpriteKit.(**I don't know is it the right way...**)

I have SKScene that includes some animated contents.

Can I get some help on how to convert the SKScene to a video file?

**SKScene Class**

```
class MyScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let box2 = SKLabelNode(text: "HELLOO")
        box2.fontSize = 60
        box2.color = .white
        box2.position = CGPoint(x: (scene?.size.width ?? 0) / 2, y: (scene?.size.height ?? 0) / 2 - 80)
        addChild(box2)
        
        let actualDuration = 3
        let actionMove: SKAction = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100),
                                                 duration: TimeInterval(actualDuration))
        
        box2.run(SKAction.sequence([actionMove]))
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793934/how-to-start-replaykit-screen-recording-in-spritekit-skscene-class

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. It doesn't seem to be the solution because this allows us to record the screen. If the video length is 30 minutes, we have to wait 30 minutes for the recording to finish.